# How to type a question mark without using the shift key in Swype?

Tags: swype

One of the reasons Swype is so great is, of course, that I can write very fast no matter how lenghty is a word. But whenever I have to use a question mark, or an exclamation, I have to hit the shift key, then the punctuation, then shift again to continue writing. Is is possible to have a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fastest way I've found is to actually swipe from the "m/?" or "z/!" keys directly to the space bar. That'll insert a punctuation mark and then a space. In the same fashion, you can insert a period or a comma. The other similar shortcut I use creates an "'s" by swiping from the apostrophe to the "s".

Some similar suggestions can be found in Swype's online reference, specifically in the "Swype Gestures" section of http://www.swype.com/tips/advanced-tips/.

Comment: +1 For providing some nice shortcuts I never knew about along with a website where's there's more.

Comment: perfect, thank you! :) I knew about period-space and also comma-space, but I had no idea m-space and z-space would also work.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of those shortcuts and I believe they will be very useful to me when ending sentences.

Comment: + 1 for making my favorite keyboard even faster!

Comment: No more long-pressing `M` for me!

Answer (score 13):

You do not have to use shift, if you hold down the 'm' key for a longer time it will insert its alt key,  a question mark.

Comment: +1 In fact anything on the top of any of the keys can be entered by long-pressing on the key for about half a second. If you long-press for even longer (around a second) you get a mini-menu popup with even more options for that key.

Comment: +1 for you. I've had my Android for nearly 5 months and I didn't know this.

Comment: It wasn't until I got Swype that I realized the same thing (holding the key down) works for the standard Android keyboard too.

Comment: Long-press works but unfortunately leads to the same problem from using shift: it takes longer time than just swiping.